# Uploading files to Web Service using RestSharp

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, webservice-client, restsharp

I'm trying to create a WebService that will accept the upload of multiple files. To post this data to the Webservice, im using RestSharp.

For the purpose of this post, I've stripped the code back.

I have the interface for my service:

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface ISender
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    int Upload(Stream fileStream);
}
```

The implementation of the Interface:

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Sender : ISender
{
    public int Upload(Stream fileStream)
    {
        FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream(Path.Combine("D:\\FileUpload\\","test.png"), FileMode.Create);

        byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
        int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead > 0);

        fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
        fileToupload.Close();
        fileToupload.Dispose();

        return 1;
    }
   }
```

And then the client code that calls the service, using RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://myserviceurl/emailsender/Sender.svc");

        var request = new RestRequest("Upload", Method.POST) {RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json};
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("/img/carousel-sprite-160.png"));
        request.AddFile("fileStream", bytes, "carousel-sprite-160.png", "image/png");


        // execute the request
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Two questions if i may:

1) The fileStream parameter in the Upload method is always null - why? What have I configured incorrectly?. Secondly, if the .AddFile method is creating a Stream object, why is it adding the name of the file and the mime-type, neither of those are part of a stream (FileStream maybe).

2) The .AddFile method can be called multiple times on the same request object. That would indicate that the webservice can receive multiple files - but how does a webservice receive multiple files? It's not possible to use `List<Stream>` so I don't understand how this is possible.

Any pointers anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Regards,
dotdev

Comment: Can you provide the `<system.servicemodel>` element of your `web.config` please?